# Using Scala Toolbox eval, how do I define I value I can use in later evals?

Tags: scala, eval

I'm using Scala toolbox to eval some Scala code for a web interpreter. It is working well, the code looks like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object Eval {
  val toolbox = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()

  def eval[T](code: String): T = {
    toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse(code)).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

I can do something like:

```
Eval.eval[Long]("1 + 1")
```

and get `2` back. The question comes up when I want to define something:

```
Eval.eval[Unit]("val yellow = 5")
Eval.eval[Long]("yellow")
```

I get a `not found: value yellow` error. How do I define a value that I can use in later evaluations with Scala Toolbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a persistent environment, you can use Scala's REPL directly. See the JSR-223 note at the very bottom of the [2.11 release notes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/).

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

class DummyClass

object Evaluator {
  val engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
  val settings = engine.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain].settings
  settings.embeddedDefaults[DummyClass]
  engine.eval("val x: Int = 5")
  val thing = engine.eval("x + 9").asInstanceOf[Int]
}
```

The need for `DummyClass` (or really any class you have can substitute for `DummyClass`) arises from a bit of shenanigans going on here [due to SBT and classloader concerns](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Faq.html#How+do+I+use+the+Scala+interpreter+in+my+code%3F) (more details [here](https://gist.github.com/harrah/404272)).

Comment: Ah this is great! The only issue now is how do I get the exception that occurred *inside* the engine if there was an error in the script? Right now it just returns a ScriptException and `.getMessage()` returns `javax.script.ScriptException: compile-time error`, even though the actual cause gets printed to terminal?